# Web view doesn't show HTML

Tags: java, html, webview, javafx

I'm trying to show some HTML on a JavaFx Pane but the HTML doesn't show. What could I be doing wrong?

***The HTML:***

```
<style type="text/css">
#Wrrpr {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #930;
    border: 1px dashed #090;
    height: 95px;
    width: 116px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Wrrpr">Sample Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***An extract from the Controller Class:***

```
Pane webView = new Pane();
WebView browser = new WebView();
browser.setMaxWidth(116);
browser.setMaxHeight(95);
WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
String urlPage = "/WakiliProject/sampleWebView.html";
engine.load(urlPage);
webView.getChildren().add(browser);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the html to a `URL` before it can be passed to the WebEngine.

Please add the following lines in your controller

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/WakiliProject/sampleWebView.html");
engine.load(url.toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Hi [ItachiUchiha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759128/itachiuchiha). I've been really struggling with [this(How to add JQuery onto JavaFx WebView)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947543/how-to-add-jquery-onto-javafx-webview) for a really long time now and was wondering whether you could help. I hope you can. It's an important part of my project. Thank you for the help so far. Really appreciate it.